# Syntax *ngFor='...' angular 2

Tags: angular

Help with syntax please. 
I would parse two objects (displaying data in table) ->

```
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let service_rec of list.servicelist" *ngFor= "let service_rec of list.storagelist">
            <td> {{ service_rec.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ service_rec.status }}</td>
            <td>{{ service_rec.total | byteFormat }}</td>
            <td>{{ service_rec.used | byteFormat }}</td>
            <td>{{ service_rec.free | byteFormat }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

How combine (with syntax) list.servicelict & list.storagelist,

i have error "NaN undefined"

UPD:

```
    <div class="panel-header text-center">
    <h1> Тест блок </h1>
</div>

<div class="row" *ngFor="let list of lists">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <caption>{{ list.nodename }}</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Название сервиса</th>
                <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Статус</th>
                <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">Файловая система</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Всего</th>
                <th>Использовано</th>
                <th>Доступно</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template ngFor let-service_rec [ngForOf]="list.servicelist">
            <tr  *ngFor= "let service_rec of list.storagelist">
                <td> {{ service_rec.name }} </td>
                <td style="width: 15%">
                    <span [style.background-color]="service_rec.status == 'Online' ? 'green' : 'red'" class="label label-default">
                        {{ service_rec.status }}
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>{{ service_rec.total | byteFormat }}</td>
                <td>{{ service_rec.used | byteFormat }}</td>
                <td>{{ service_rec.free | byteFormat }}</td>
            </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

When i add

```
<template>...</template>
```

data in row "Название сервиса" & "Статус" are gone

```
 [
  {"nodename":"192.124.105.55",
   "servicelist":[
      {
         "id":"ec9471ec001c10b9fa286e1f52e39c5dc9485a7c2cfbf55145c26242bb98ec4d",
         "name":"Nginx",
         "status":"Online",
         "servicecontrolled":true
       },
       {
          "id":"f4ca9e0badc6b23e3e36444bd7ee4a9efcd39de8e0bb4cdecb25b5a02ef86ba5",
          "name":"Memcached",
          "status":"Offline",
         "servicecontrolled":true        
       },
        {
          "id":"0a4bf3b5bb5f47ece9284052389ae02f6c9dba989ca34086a30e049ee3d8eb47",
          "name":"Celery",
          "status":"Offline",
         "servicecontrolled":true
         }
     ],
  "storagelist":
  [
     {
       "mountpoint":"/",
       "total":188,
       "used":28,
       "free":161
    },
   {
       "mountpoint":"/boot",
       "total":235,
       "used":106,
       "free":129
     }
  ]
```

this error -> [image: click]

Comment: It's not possible to figure out where "NaN undefined" is coming from without seeing what actual data you are using. It would be best if you create a Plunker that demonstrates the issue. You can use this template https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: That doesn't help. I still don't see what data you're using. Please create a Plunker.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer my data is a parse of json, i edit code

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to be related to combining two `ngFor`, maybe caused by your `byteFormat` pipe. How do you want to combine these two lists anyway?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer i load image with my table, and problem in not with byteFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two structural directives on the same element (2 x `*ngFor`)
If you need more than one you need to use the form with an explicit `<template>` tag:

```
<tbody>
  <template ngFor let-service_rec [ngForOf]="list.servicelist">
    <tr *ngFor= "let service_rec of list.storagelist">
        <td> {{ service_rec.name }} </td>
        <td> {{ service_rec.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ service_rec.total | byteFormat }}</td>
        <td>{{ service_rec.used | byteFormat }}</td>
        <td>{{ service_rec.free | byteFormat }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```